# How to get product review details in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, review

I want to get product rating details based on product id. can you anyone help me how to get details programmatically in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

Below code may help you.

```
$_productID = 101;
$_product=$this->_objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($_productID);
$_review=$this->_objectManager->create("Magento\Review\Model\Review");
$_reviewFact=$this->_objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory");
$_reviewFact->create()->getEntitySummary($_product, 1);  
//Below code will get the rating summary
print_r($_product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary());
```

Comment: please help me to get the reviews.The above code returns the rating percentage of products only.